# VERSION CONTROL - i'd like to use an Accurev CLI command to copy files to my workstation associated to issue numbers

Tags: command-line-interface, accurev

Can you please advise if there's a way to use a CLI command to copy down files from AccuRev associated to a given issue number?

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a single command to accomplish this, but the information is readily available.  You can run a command like "accurev cpkdescribe" to find out what files and versions are currently part of a Change Package:

`c:\AccuRev\bin>accurev cpkdescribe -p Support -I 2111
Issue: 2111
/com.accurev.ide.common/src/com/accurev/ide/common/parsers/AccuRevHandler.java 52/1 2/1

/com.accurev.ide.common/src/com/accurev/ide/common/parsers/ShowUsersParser.java 52/1 2/1

/com.accurev.ide.common/src/com/accurev/ide/common/process/ElementProcess.java 52/1 2/1

/FileLister/FileLister.java 52/1 38/1

/RemoveSCC/AssemblyInfo.cs 52/1 38/1

/FileLister/W2L-Installation.txt 52/1 0/0

/FileLister/W2L-README.txt 52/1 0/0

/RemoveSCC/W2L-Installation.txt 52/1 0/0

/RemoveSCC/W2L-README.txt 52/1 0/0`

You can even run this with -fx to retrieve the information in xml format.  You then parse that output for the file name (location attribute) and version (real_version attribute or the first version from the non-xml output) and pass it into an "accurev pop" command.

It's actually quite simple in practice and can easily be made into a basic script which takes the depot name and issue number as parameters and pops to a specific location.  The accurev command-line is very flexible so you can explore these options as necessary...

Hope this helps,
~James